Clarification on React Reconciliation: Comparing React Element with Fiber Nodes in work-in-progress and current trees
I am trying to understand the reconciliation process in React, specifically how it handles updates and comparisons between React elements and Fiber nodes.
As I understand it:

During the initial rendering, React creates a tree of React elements
from JSX and then builds a Fiber tree with nodes corresponding to
each element.
When setState is called, the relevant Fiber node is marked for
update, triggering the creation of a work-in-progress tree. Fiber
nodes that haven’t changed are cloned from the current tree, while in
the component where setState occurred, a new tree of React elements
is generated.

Questions:

During reconciliation, is the new React element compared against the
Fiber node from the current tree, or is it wrapped in a new Fiber
node, and then the comparison is between Fiber nodes from the
work-in-progress tree and the current tree?
Additionally, does the reconciliation process begin only after the
work-in-progress tree is fully constructed, or does it proceed
incrementally as each node in the work-in-progress tree is generated?

I’d appreciate any insights into these specific aspects of React’s reconciliation and update mechanism!

https://7km.top/algorithm/diff#%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E5%8E%9F%E7%90%86 answer on first question
